# When I Start my Windows 11 computer, the terminal pops up saying: Error writing proxy settings. (5) Access is denied

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-11, windows-terminal

### Problem

Sometimes when I start my Windows 11 computer, the terminal pops up with an error message: `Error writing proxy settings. (5) Access is denied.` This does not happen every time, but I will occasionally see it.

### Error message

```
Error writing proxy settings. (5) Access is denied.


Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).


[process exited with code 1]
```

[image]

---

May I know what this is and if this is a serious problem?

Comment: This is not Windows 11 behaviour. Do you have a startup setting in Terminal causing this?

Comment: @John I checked, it is disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I already disabled things that are not necessary and it does not show up anymore.

Comment: @Ramhound ok. Is there any way for me to close this question?

Comment: I have the same issue, even after disabling everything in startup apps and using AutoRuns. After the lock screen on the first boot, the terminal opens automatically displaying the error.

Comment: Just happened to me.
Lets see what we have in common: my is dev machine for dotnet, node, wsl. Lenovo thinkpad x13, amd.

Comment: Just happened to me today as well.

Comment: I also saw it today again! I think I should edit the question.

Comment: @Ramhound How did you get the idea of closing a issue after it resolved from author end? There are millions of other user who may face similar issue and there may be lots more way to solve them. So you should always keep the question open.

Comment: If someone says they solved their ow. problem with a comment, I am always going to vote to close the question, as an indication an answer should be submitted instead. If the someone else has the same question they can ask it, provide more details, and receive an answer. If the community disagrees with that fact, vote to open the question, and someone can answer the question.  Although at this point, I have answered it, and would vote to close this question as a duplicate of the question I answered.

Comment: @Ramhound I have the same problem and the exact same question. What other details are necessary? Please keep this question open so that people actually benefit from it instead of closing it down for "lack of details"---whatever that means.

Comment: A moderator closed this question and the reason for its closure hasn’t been addressed. I submitted an answer to a possible duplicate more than a month ago. If you have the same question, ask your own question, and provide enough information to answer your question.  I must warn you that there are at least 6 questions about Windows Terminal and WinHTTP and are all likely caused by the same erroneous configuration

Comment: @Tfovid - Feel free to submit your own question in that case.