# Windows Terminal opens on startup with proxy error

Tags: windows, terminal, proxy, netsh, windows-terminal

> **Note:** This is a duplicate of [When I Start my Windows 11 computer, the terminal pops up saying: Error writing proxy settings. (5) Access is denied](https://superuser.com/q/1684628/875490) which has no clear solution for this problem, as it was closed because the OP said their problem was solved in the comments.

When I start my computer, `netsh.exe` opens in Windows Terminal with the following error:

```
Error writing proxy settings. (5) Access is denied.


Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).


[process exited with code 1]
```

[image: Windows Terminal proxy error]

This error only began occurring after I added Git Bash to Windows Terminal by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58027771/12860895).

This is my `settings.json` configuration file for Windows Terminal:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",
  "actions": [
    {
      "command": {
        "action": "copy",
        "singleLine": false
      },
      "keys": "ctrl+c"
    },
    {
      "command": "paste",
      "keys": "ctrl+v"
    },
    {
      "command": "find",
      "keys": "ctrl+shift+f"
    },
    {
      "command": {
        "action": "splitPane",
        "split": "auto",
        "splitMode": "duplicate"
      },
      "keys": "alt+shift+d"
    }
  ],
  "copyFormatting": "none",
  "copyOnSelect": false,
  "defaultProfile": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}",
  "profiles": {
    "defaults": {
      
    },
    "list": [
      {
        "commandline": "powershell.exe",
        "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
        "hidden": false,
        "name": "Windows PowerShell"
      },
      {
        "commandline": "cmd.exe",
        "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
        "hidden": false,
        "name": "Command Prompt"
      },
      {
        "guid": "{b453ae62-4e3d-5e58-b989-0a998ec441b8}",
        "hidden": false,
        "name": "Azure Cloud Shell",
        "source": "Windows.Terminal.Azure"
      },
      {
        "acrylicOpacity": 0.75,
        "closeOnExit": "graceful",
        "colorScheme": "GitBash",
        "commandline": "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe\" --login -i -l",
        "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "cursorShape": "bar",
        "font": {
          "face": "Consolas",
          "size": 10
        },
        "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}",
        "historySize": 9001,
        "icon": "%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
        "name": "GitBash",
        "padding": "0, 0, 0, 0",
        "snapOnInput": true,
        "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%",
        "useAcrylic": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "schemes": [
    {
      "background": "#0C0C0C",
      "black": "#0C0C0C",
      "blue": "#0037DA",
      "brightBlack": "#767676",
      "brightBlue": "#3B78FF",
      "brightCyan": "#61D6D6",
      "brightGreen": "#16C60C",
      "brightPurple": "#B4009E",
      "brightRed": "#E74856",
      "brightWhite": "#F2F2F2",
      "brightYellow": "#F9F1A5",
      "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "cyan": "#3A96DD",
      "foreground": "#CCCCCC",
      "green": "#13A10E",
      "name": "Campbell",
      "purple": "#881798",
      "red": "#C50F1F",
      "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "white": "#CCCCCC",
      "yellow": "#C19C00"
    },
    {
      "background": "#012456",
      "black": "#0C0C0C",
      "blue": "#0037DA",
      "brightBlack": "#767676",
      "brightBlue": "#3B78FF",
      "brightCyan": "#61D6D6",
      "brightGreen": "#16C60C",
      "brightPurple": "#B4009E",
      "brightRed": "#E74856",
      "brightWhite": "#F2F2F2",
      "brightYellow": "#F9F1A5",
      "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "cyan": "#3A96DD",
      "foreground": "#CCCCCC",
      "green": "#13A10E",
      "name": "Campbell Powershell",
      "purple": "#881798",
      "red": "#C50F1F",
      "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "white": "#CCCCCC",
      "yellow": "#C19C00"
    },
    {
      "background": "#000000",
      "black": "#0C0C0C",
      "blue": "#6060FF",
      "brightBlack": "#767676",
      "brightBlue": "#3B78FF",
      "brightCyan": "#61D6D6",
      "brightGreen": "#16C60C",
      "brightPurple": "#B4009E",
      "brightRed": "#E74856",
      "brightWhite": "#F2F2F2",
      "brightYellow": "#F9F1A5",
      "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "cyan": "#3A96DD",
      "foreground": "#BFBFBF",
      "green": "#00A400",
      "name": "GitBash",
      "purple": "#BF00BF",
      "red": "#BF0000",
      "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "white": "#FFFFFF",
      "yellow": "#BFBF00"
    },
    {
      "background": "#282C34",
      "black": "#282C34",
      "blue": "#61AFEF",
      "brightBlack": "#5A6374",
      "brightBlue": "#61AFEF",
      "brightCyan": "#56B6C2",
      "brightGreen": "#98C379",
      "brightPurple": "#C678DD",
      "brightRed": "#E06C75",
      "brightWhite": "#DCDFE4",
      "brightYellow": "#E5C07B",
      "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "cyan": "#56B6C2",
      "foreground": "#DCDFE4",
      "green": "#98C379",
      "name": "One Half Dark",
      "purple": "#C678DD",
      "red": "#E06C75",
      "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "white": "#DCDFE4",
      "yellow": "#E5C07B"
    },
    {
      "background": "#FAFAFA",
      "black": "#383A42",
      "blue": "#0184BC",
      "brightBlack": "#4F525D",
      "brightBlue": "#61AFEF",
      "brightCyan": "#56B5C1",
      "brightGreen": "#98C379",
      "brightPurple": "#C577DD",
      "brightRed": "#DF6C75",
      "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
      "brightYellow": "#E4C07A",
      "cursorColor": "#4F525D",
      "cyan": "#0997B3",
      "foreground": "#383A42",
      "green": "#50A14F",
      "name": "One Half Light",
      "purple": "#A626A4",
      "red": "#E45649",
      "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "white": "#FAFAFA",
      "yellow": "#C18301"
    },
    {
      "background": "#002B36",
      "black": "#002B36",
      "blue": "#268BD2",
      "brightBlack": "#073642",
      "brightBlue": "#839496",
      "brightCyan": "#93A1A1",
      "brightGreen": "#586E75",
      "brightPurple": "#6C71C4",
      "brightRed": "#CB4B16",
      "brightWhite": "#FDF6E3",
      "brightYellow": "#657B83",
      "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "cyan": "#2AA198",
      "foreground": "#839496",
      "green": "#859900",
      "name": "Solarized Dark",
      "purple": "#D33682",
      "red": "#DC322F",
      "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "white": "#EEE8D5",
      "yellow": "#B58900"
    },
    {
      "background": "#FDF6E3",
      "black": "#002B36",
      "blue": "#268BD2",
      "brightBlack": "#073642",
      "brightBlue": "#839496",
      "brightCyan": "#93A1A1",
      "brightGreen": "#586E75",
      "brightPurple": "#6C71C4",
      "brightRed": "#CB4B16",
      "brightWhite": "#FDF6E3",
      "brightYellow": "#657B83",
      "cursorColor": "#002B36",
      "cyan": "#2AA198",
      "foreground": "#657B83",
      "green": "#859900",
      "name": "Solarized Light",
      "purple": "#D33682",
      "red": "#DC322F",
      "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "white": "#EEE8D5",
      "yellow": "#B58900"
    },
    {
      "background": "#000000",
      "black": "#000000",
      "blue": "#3465A4",
      "brightBlack": "#555753",
      "brightBlue": "#729FCF",
      "brightCyan": "#34E2E2",
      "brightGreen": "#8AE234",
      "brightPurple": "#AD7FA8",
      "brightRed": "#EF2929",
      "brightWhite": "#EEEEEC",
      "brightYellow": "#FCE94F",
      "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "cyan": "#06989A",
      "foreground": "#D3D7CF",
      "green": "#4E9A06",
      "name": "Tango Dark",
      "purple": "#75507B",
      "red": "#CC0000",
      "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "white": "#D3D7CF",
      "yellow": "#C4A000"
    },
    {
      "background": "#FFFFFF",
      "black": "#000000",
      "blue": "#3465A4",
      "brightBlack": "#555753",
      "brightBlue": "#729FCF",
      "brightCyan": "#34E2E2",
      "brightGreen": "#8AE234",
      "brightPurple": "#AD7FA8",
      "brightRed": "#EF2929",
      "brightWhite": "#EEEEEC",
      "brightYellow": "#FCE94F",
      "cursorColor": "#000000",
      "cyan": "#06989A",
      "foreground": "#555753",
      "green": "#4E9A06",
      "name": "Tango Light",
      "purple": "#75507B",
      "red": "#CC0000",
      "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "white": "#D3D7CF",
      "yellow": "#C4A000"
    },
    {
      "background": "#000000",
      "black": "#000000",
      "blue": "#000080",
      "brightBlack": "#808080",
      "brightBlue": "#0000FF",
      "brightCyan": "#00FFFF",
      "brightGreen": "#00FF00",
      "brightPurple": "#FF00FF",
      "brightRed": "#FF0000",
      "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
      "brightYellow": "#FFFF00",
      "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "cyan": "#008080",
      "foreground": "#C0C0C0",
      "green": "#008000",
      "name": "Vintage",
      "purple": "#800080",
      "red": "#800000",
      "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
      "white": "#C0C0C0",
      "yellow": "#808000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a screenshot of an entry causing a terminal to be automatically started at user logon, from Autoruns:

[image: cmd.exe entry in Autoruns]

I can't find any others, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>ing for `netsh` yields no relevant results.

What is causing this error and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

> What is causing this error and how do I solve it?

The installation of an unspecified application has added an entry to your registry, causing it to automatically start netsh.exe within a Command Prompt or PowerShell prompt when you log into your user, due to the default profile being Git-Bash this unspecified action fails and is the source of your error. You can either delete this registry key or change the default shell within Windows Terminal.

The simplest solution is to just modify settings.json and change the following:

```
"defaultProfile": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}",
```

to

```
"defaultProfile": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
```

As for the cause of the error, you have an entry within your registry that is attempting to start a terminal when you log into your user profile.  Due to the fact your default profile is Git Bash which is incompatible with netsh.exe, the netsh.exe action fails and generates the error your asking about.  The line causing this behavior is the following:

```
 "commandline": "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe\" --login -i -l",
```

The behavior you describe can be avoid by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839307/adding-git-bash-to-the-new-windows-terminal/69093260#69093260) to [Adding Git-Bash to the new Windows Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839307/adding-git-bash-to-the-new-windows-terminal) instead of configuring Git-Bash as the default profile for Windows Terminal.