# Windows terminal open on startup with proxy error

Tags: terminal, proxy, netsh

Every time I start my computer (Windows 11)  windows terminal opened in **C:\WINDOWS\system32\netsh.exe** pops up with an error:

```
Error writing proxy settings. (5) Access is denied.


Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).


[process exited with code 1]
```

Unfortunately, I can't remember a specific moment when the error started to occur. I've tried disabling every start up process but it didn't work. I also found the same problem ([Windows Terminal opens on startup with proxy error](https://superuser.com/questions/1686316/windows-terminal-opens-on-startup-with-proxy-error))  and followed the solution (changing default terminal to cmd.exe, as git-bash can't work with netsh.exe) as I have git-bash installed on my computer, but it didn't help. What my be the cause of this error?

Comment: The solution in your link was not "changing default terminal to cmd.exe". Did you try everything it said?

Comment: Yes, I modified settings.json file as in given link. However I don't know how to find the registry key that is said to be causing the problem

Comment: Does it happen if you run Windows terminal as Administrator?

Comment: I don't run terminal manually - it opens every time on it's own when I launch the system, so I cannot choose if I want to run it as admin.

Comment: You can't run another instance as Admin?

Comment: Ah okay, sorry. I can run it as Admin, but I don't know what command to execute after I run netsh.exe

Comment: Sometimes such a problem is solved by just running the program as Admin once.

Comment: Unfortunately running netsh.exe as admin doesn't change anything